# Make new column in data frame with headers of other columns

Tags: r, dataframe

Is have a data frame which looks like this

```
Forest Grass Shrub Water Binary
0.6    0.5   0.3   0.2   1
0.2    0.3   0.4   0.5   0
0.3    0.5   0.2   0.6   1
0.2    0.6   0.3   0.2   0
0.6    0.5   0.3   0.2   1
```

I want R to look at all rows and
write me in a new colum the name of the land cover with the biggest number so that i have a table like this.

```
Forest Grass Shrub Water Binary Most
0.6    0.5   0.3   0.2   1      Forest
0.2    0.3   0.4   0.5   0      Water
0.3    0.5   0.2   0.6   1      Water
0.2    0.6   0.3   0.2   0      Grass
0.6    0.5   0.3   0.2   1      Forest
```

Then I want R to look at the Binary Column and to make a count on how often the combination forest-1 forest-0, water-1, water-0 appears

Unfortunately I have NO clue on how to do this and would appreciate your help!

Comment: -1; show what you've tried

Comment: There are several `name`-commands in R to get the names of columns of object (several because there are different types of objects), e.g. `names(your.data)`, `colnames(your.data)` or `col.names(your.data)`. Once you have your column names in a vector, you are probably able to figure out the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Update

Instead of `apply`, you can also use `max.col`, like this:

```
names(mydf)[max.col(mydf[-length(mydf)])]
# [1] "Forest" "Water"  "Water"  "Grass"  "Forest"
```

---

#### Original answer

By the sounds of it, you might be looking for something like this:

```
## Create your "Most" column. 
## This assumes "Binary" to be the last column. 
## Use names along with `setdiff`, index positions, or other approaches
##     if this is not the case with your actual data.
mydf$Most <- apply(mydf[-length(mydf)], 1, function(x) names(x)[which.max(x)])
mydf
#   Forest Grass Shrub Water Binary   Most
# 1    0.6   0.5   0.3   0.2      1 Forest
# 2    0.2   0.3   0.4   0.5      0  Water
# 3    0.3   0.5   0.2   0.6      1  Water
# 4    0.2   0.6   0.3   0.2      0  Grass
# 5    0.6   0.5   0.3   0.2      1 Forest

## This is the tabulation step.
## I'm assuming this is separate from the original data.frame
##     as it isn't shown to be as part of your desired output.
table(mydf[c("Most", "Binary")])
#         Binary
# Most     0 1
#   Forest 0 2
#   Grass  1 0
#   Water  1 1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)
setDT(dt)
dt[,RowNo := .I]

dt2 <- melt(dt[,c(setdiff(colnames(dt),'Binary')), with = F], id.vars = c('RowNo'))
dt2 <- unique(dt2[, Most := as.character(variable)[which.max(value)], by = RowNo][,list(RowNo,Most)])

dt <- merge(dt2,dt, by = 'RowNo')

dt[,list(.N), by = list(Binary,Most)]
```

Output -

```
   Binary   Most N
1:      1 Forest 2
2:      0  Water 1
3:      1  Water 1
4:      0  Grass 1
```

Comment: as far as I understand this also includes the Binary colum when looking for the colum with the biggest number, is there a way to ignore this colum? I think the `colClass` argument is not working in this case?

Comment: You're right. I made an edit, this should work now.

Also, I don't see how you can use `colClass` here. I highly recommend learing and practicing R from some course on Coursera or any of the multiple online tutorials

Comment: the output i get is in the form i want it! However, output i get looks very symestric which cannot be true..

Comment: Can you post what you expect your output to be?

Comment: From the structure the output is exactly as I want it. It sums up the occunrence of classes with all 1's and all 0's.
But  the values are too similair, the sum  for all the 1 are around 3000 for every class, and for the 0's around 400 vor every class. I expect a more "varied / uneven" output. 
(I look at land covers in the United States and take the biggest land cover occurence per 0.5°Lat/lon, then I compare every cell to 1/0 (bushfire in cell/ no bushfire in cell) ) I hope you get what I mean

Comment: I've posted the dataset I have and the result I'm getting. They match. If you can't point out exactly what the error is or post your actual data, there isn't much I can do.

Comment: I think something goes wrong with the 'dt[,Most := setdiff(colnames(dt),'Binary')]' line. it does not take the highest value (eg: Most for 2 should be Water instead of Grass)

Comment: I'm sorry, I just realised that I missed out this part - " new colum the name of the land cover with the biggest number". Let me try and fix it. Or you can use Ananda's solution.

Comment: Changed. I deserved that -1 whoever gave it.

Comment: seems to work! thanks!! I did not downvote you, but i have not enough credits to upvote unfortunately! Although Anadas solution is more understandable for me when I look at it, the binary is included in the table so it doesnt work yet!

Comment: @user3476078, I'm still not clear on what you mean by "the binary is included in the table so it doesn't work yet". Can you update your question.

Comment: At the moment it also takes the binary column into account when looking at the largest number in the row, but i need only the biggest number from the Land Cover Columns..